# How to access child class object that inherits parent class?

Tags: python, django, class

I have parent class and child class, that inherits parent class. And that is okay, I can iterate with for loop. Now I want to access child class (example: 'product_type' So basically, I'm confused how we inherits stuff from child class inside the same loop...

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from . models import Category
from django.shortcuts import render

class CategoryListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category_list.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
    
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Category name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Product name')
    # product_spec = models.TextField(max_length=5000, help_text='Product specs')
    product_type = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

category_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block body %}

{% for page in category_list %}
    <li>{{ page.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ page.product_name }} # <--------------- Now this is the point of 
                                                   #my problem, I want to get 
                                                   #product name from child 
                                                   #class 
                                                   #this returns empty <li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block body %}

{% for page in category_list %}
    <li>{{ page.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ page.product_set.first.product_name }} 
product name from child class, this returns empty <li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `page.product_set.first.product_name` doesn't solve the inherent problem that their will be multiple products of same category

Answer (score 0):

First off change your `product_type` name to just `category` its way easier to understand and add an attribute `related_name` to it like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Product name')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='products')
```

then in your template

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for product in category.products.all %}
        {{ product.name}}
        ... other product data
    {% endfor %}
{% endfior %}
```

Comment: Yes this has to work, just make sure you include the `related_name` attribute and rename the fields according to my answer.

Comment: They blocked me from asking question, lol. Weirdos! Btw found another way to do this. Unfortunately your way did't work. 
My next step going deeper, I want to print instances (separated from the rest of products) for example:
- page1.html contains only phone models
- page2.html contains only earphones models...etc
Any advice?

Comment: add a `Category` Model and add a foreign key on a `Product` to it, then create some categories and assign products to them, then filter the products with their respective category

Answer (score -1):

`product_type`in `Product` is a `ForaignKey` which means their will be multiple products having same `Category` so their exist two solutions

1. make `product_type` in `Product` one to one key, with this you shuld get single name by `{{ page.product.product_name }}`
2. print list of all products of the category, you can do this by iterating `page.product_set` as it is a list (iterable) with for loop.

Comment: Making the relationship `OneToOne` would mean that 1 category can only have 1 product and that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @SLDem I dont know the business logic; my answer includes both cases.

Comment: @SLDem Okay, I got 'Phones Earphones', but that is all, I don't get name of it...

Comment: read my answer, I renamed the field on the `Product` model

Comment: @SLDem I know, just copied your code, but still don't show everything it should. This is madness

Comment: did you run `makemigrations`?

Comment: and please respond under my answer

Comment: class ProductName(models.Model):
    buyer =  models.ForeignKey('Buyer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='buyer')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Buyer(models.Model):
    first_name =    models.CharField(max_length=200)
    buyed_item =  models.ForeignKey('ProductName', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, related_name='buyed_item')

Can u tell me how can I access buyer first_name, but inside ProductName template {% for product in productname_list %} ? Not inside 'buyer_list.html'